# write to socketchannel from one thread and select from other thread

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Can I write to `SocketChannel` from one thread, while same `SocketChannel` may be being selected by `Selector#select()` for IO operations in other thread? Is it thread-safe? Or do I have to delegate `ByteBuffer`s to other thread (which do `Selector#select()` indefinitely), to be written to `SocketChannel` every after `Selector#select()` calls.

Also, is `SelectionKey#interestOps(int)` to set interest operations thread-safe? Or do I have to delegate same to other thread (which do `Selector#select()` indefinitely).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,in general. The thread that's blocked in `select()` isn't using the `ByteBuffer` while it's blocked. If it does so elsewhere, of course you need to synchronize, or take some other measure.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So `Selector#select(long)` and `SocketChannel#write(ByteBuffer)` are thread-safe?

Comment: Also, if it is thread-safe, to write full `ByteBuffer`, I may write as much as possible `ByteBuffer` from writer thread, and then writer thread invoke `SelectionKey#interestOps(int)` to update `OP_WRITE`, and selector thread completes full buffer writing when `key.isWritable()`. So is `SelectionKey#interestOps(int)` and `Selector#select(long)` thread-safe?

Comment: Or it is better to just handoff write operation completely to selector thread?

Comment: Whether `select()` or `write()` are thread-safe is a different question. I just said they are safe *from each other.* It isn't the same thing.

Comment: I am asking is: Whether `select()` and `write()` are thread-safe?